# Can I use Australian dollars at the Kuala Lumpur airport?

Tags: money, malaysia, kul

I'm facing a four hour layover at Kuala Lumpur airport on my way to Australia and I was wondering if the food outlets in the airport will accept Australian dollars? I don't particularly want to face the steep commission rates of the bureau to change for a mere cup of coffee.

Comment: How about getting exchanging currency at an airport only so that u don't have to worry

Comment: use credit card.

Answer (score 2):

They did take USD as far as I remember, but not AUD since it would be a hassle for the retailers to keep notes and change for each country in the register.
Otherwise just use your credit card, that's what everyone is doing there who does not want to exchange cash.